# how to make user come back to the same page after login

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

In asp.net 3.5, i am trying to send a user to a different https url to login, if the user is not logged in.  I am kinda' restricting the user not to see the forum page in the current site (http://thisSite.com/forum.aspx), if the user is not logged in.

I am not sure how to redirect the user back from the login page (https://somethirdpartysite.com) back to the http://thisSite.com/forum.aspx

i tried placing response.redirect in my forum.aspx like this:
response.redirect("https://somethirdpartysite.com"), but it's not behaving as expected.

Any pointers would help me.

Regards,
Ron.

Comment: sounds like you're contradicting what you want. do you want to direct the user from login page to forum page, or forum page to login/3rdparty page?

Comment: from forum page to login/3rd party page and once logged in, back to forum page.

Comment: Oh, i see. i misunderstood; deleted my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ReturnUrl` Query Strign key: `https://somethirdpartysite.com?ReturnUrl=Forum.aspx` so after the login an user will be automatically redirected to the `Forum.aspx` page.

Comment: this throws an error from the 3rd party site as unknow error - i followed your suggestion, by placing the url like this:  Response.Redirect("https://Somethirdpartysite.com/Login.aspx" & "?ReturnUrl=forum.aspx")

Comment: @Ron : Very strange, if site is deloyed to interned can you send me exact URL to see an error? Or do you have an error/exception details?

Comment: @ Sll i am trying to go from forum.aspx to login.aspx as an SSO, and then once logged in login.aspx, the user should be returned to forum.aspx

Comment: hi Sll your solutiion worked great for me, i had some typo..thanks for your help.